# Mule WMQ Connector Scheduling

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, mule-cluster

I need to schedule a web sphere MQ connector to poll the queue every 4 hours. How can i schedule this job using mule flow?

I tried to use scheduler, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use `MuleRequestor`  when you need any outbound endpoint in action or on-demand( Example:Queue or file). Your case its WMQ.
Use poll followed by `Mule Requestor`.  Refer the below link.Instead of HTTP use Schedule, and for JMS queue use WMQ.

https://www.slideshare.net/anir37/using-mule-requester-for-jms

https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/mule-dev/introducing-the-mule-requester-module/